# How do I increase log verbosity in Docker for Windows Kubernetes API server?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, kube-apiserver

When running Docker for Windows, the level of detail in the logs for `kube-apiserver` is relatively low. Since the k8s node is hosted in a VM it is not obvious where to make changes to the default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

First, log in to the VM using the technique in this [article](https://www.bretfisher.com/getting-a-shell-in-the-docker-for-windows-vm/). Once logged in to a Unix shell, execute:

`cd /var/lib/kubeadm/manifests`

.. then edit the `kube-apiserver.yaml` using an editor such as:

`vi kube-apiserver.yaml`

Add a new line, `--v=4` in the `spec` section that determines the command:

```
spec:                                                                                                                                                       
  containers:                                                                                                                                               
  - command:                                                                                                                                                  
  - kube-apiserver                                                                                                                                          
  - --v=4
```

Save the updates, then kill the `kube-apiserver` pod so that it restarts with the new configuration.